# Get the current process path without resolving symlinks in rust, ideally cross-platform

Tags: linux, windows, unix, rust, cross-platform

As the title says, is there any way to get the directory the current process was called in, without resolving symbolic links?

For example:

My main directory contains directory `A`, which contains directory `B`, which contains my executable.

My main directory also contains directory `C`. `C` contains a symbolic link, labeled `D`, which links to `B`.

If I run my program by navigating to `C/D`, I want it to display `C/D`, and not `A/B`.

Is this possible? Ideally I'd like to be able to make it work on Linux, MacOS, and Windows.

Comment: If the path given by [`current_exe()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_exe.html) or the first argument from [`args()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.args.html) doesn't give you what you want, then I don't think anything will.

Comment: Or wait, did you want the directory of the executable or the directory it was called from? From your question it sounds like they're one and the same, but the latter would be from [`current_dir()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html).

Comment: You can't rely on the first of `args()` because it being the processes name is only a convention.

Comment: @kmdreko I want the directory it was called from, but your suggestion doesn't seem to work.